# adonisjs 3.2 delete permanent (soft delete)

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

### adonisjs 3.2 delete permanent (soft delete)

Hi, I have implemented soft delete on my project, but is there any method/function to delete permanently data from data base after I did soft delete?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can, query for the data that have deleteTimestamp with actual values (Dates Timestamps), and delete those records from your table.

First in your Lucid model(s) there is a method: deleteTimestamp that method returns the name of the column that you use to track or keep the state of  your soft deleted records.

```
class YourModelName extends Lucid {

  static get deleteTimestamp () {
     return "name_of_the_field_in_your_table_for_deleteTimestamps" 
  }
}
```

Check in your database/table (MySQL, SQLite, Pg or other) and you should that name_of_the_field_in_your_table_for_deleteTimestamps column, and you can

```
query_delete_soft = `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE
   name_of_the_field_in_your_table_for_deleteTimestamps IS NOT NULL`;
```

Use something similar to this:

```
yield Database.schema.raw(query_delete_soft); // Adonis Legacy
await Database.schema.raw(query_delete_soft); // Adonis4 (Node8)
```